# Is possible to push notification for specific users in ionic 2?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ionic2

Is ionic 2 supported pushing notification from device to other device by using firebase or any thing else ?

Because most of tutorials explain how to push for all users but I'm trying to send one to specific user/users ..

Answer (score 0):

Your sender device or your backend will need to know the receiver device registration id; You get this when the device registers with FCM for example, in my case after getting the id back I send it to my backend so I can track all the users registration Ids for whenever I need to send then a push notification.

Comment: So can u share me any useful links u learned from them how to do such as u wrote ?